# Serial data receive makes the application freeze

Tags: c#

I am working on a Windows form application, where I send data through buttons, and continuously receive data for updating some gauge values.

The trouble I am facing, is when reading the serial port, if data is coming too fast, my application responds very slow, for example I can have a data rate of 1000Hz when reading.

I have attached a simplified version of my code.

What could cause this application to hang? I read that I need some separate thread? But how to achieve this?

```
namespace Motor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort ComPort = new SerialPort();
        string InputData = String.Empty;
        delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ComPort.DataReceived += 
                new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived_1);
        }

        private void port_DataReceived_1(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            InputData = ComPort.ReadExisting();
            if (InputData != String.Empty)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextCallback(SetText), new object[] { InputData });
            }
        }

        private void SetText(string text)
        {
            if (text.Contains("CM")) 
            {
                // process the text content here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use background worker RunAsync e.Result = ComPort.ReadLine() and in the backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted eventHandler you can grab the information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ReadLine` to avoid a chunk `Data Recieved`.

```
namespace Motor
{
     delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort ComPort = new SerialPort();
        string InputData = String.Empty;
         SetTextCallback st;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            st = new SetTextCallback(SetText);

        }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         OpenPort();
    }
        private void port_DataReceived_1(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            InputData = ComPort.ReadLine();
            if (InputData != String.Empty)
            {
               this.Invoke(st,new object[] { InputData});
            }
        }

        private void SetText(string text)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(text);//To check the return value
            if (text.Contains("CM")) 
            {
                // process the text content here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There's a lot of return value in this Part `InputData`;

List of Return Value (Be careful to check this value)

```
1. OK
2. >
3. + CMGS: ID_NUMBER_HERE
4. ERROR ERROR_NUMBER_HERE
```

And any others...

Now its's depends on your code when you want to let go or continue the code with that values return.

off course before this code you already opened the `PORT`. Coz this code doesn't work anymore if the `PORT` is closed.

GUIDE TO OPEN A PORT

```
private void OpenPort()
{
      private System.IO.Ports.SerialPort ComPort;
       ComPort= new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM1");//depends on your 
     Device COM

            ComPort.NewLine = System.Environment.NewLine;
            ComPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            ComPort.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
            ComPort.DataBits = 8;
            ComPort.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
            ComPort.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;

            ComPort.ReadTimeout = 3600000;
            ComPort.WriteTimeout = 3600000;
            ComPort.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");

            GC.SuppressFinalize(ComPort);

            SerialPortFixer.Execute("COM1");

            ComPort.DataReceived += new 
   System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived_1);

            ComPort.Open();

            GC.SuppressFinalize(ComPort.BaseStream);

            ComPort.DtrEnable = true;
            ComPort.RtsEnable = true;

   }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely your issue

```
this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextCallback(SetText), new object[] { InputData });
```

If your serial port is thrashing, its trying to marshal back to the UI thread all the time. Do you really need to update the main UI thread this fast? cant you just do it every second or periodically

In regards to the statement

> What could cause this application to hang? I read that I need some
>   separate thread? But how to achieve this?

[SerialPort.DataReceived Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The DataReceived event is raised on a secondary thread when data is
>   received from the SerialPort object

I.e it is already running on secondary thread, so starting another thread is not going to help you

**Update**

In reference to your comment

> 1000hz is the data rate coming from the hardware, its no need for the
>   GUI to be that fast, but i want the gauges to move smooth.

You can still make them smooth, still at least preventing UI throttling would be your key, try buffering for 200-300 milliseconds or so. I.e just play around with it

Comment: Hello, 1000hz is the data rate coming from the hardware,   its no need for the GUI to be that fast,  but i want the gauges to move smooth. I will try latter your solutions and come back with a update. Thank you everyone

Answer (score -1):

I do not have any example code which is written but i can suggest you to use **threads** or **background workers** to read data, it is really easy to understand useage of background workers or threads. You can watch short tutorials. Try to create a button which starts background worker and with that background worker, you can read your data **without freezing**. Sorry i do not have time to write example but in my opinion these are the **topics** you should be **focusing** on **(Bakcground workers or Threads)**

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

try implement async await

more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513(v=vs.120).aspx

Here's a quick example (although I can't verify it because I don't have the necessary requirements for running the code, but should give an idea):

```
namespace Motor
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SerialPort ComPort = new SerialPort();
    string InputData = String.Empty;
    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ComPort.DataReceived +=
            new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived_1);
    }

    private async void port_DataReceived_1(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var size = ComPort.ReadBufferSize;
        var data = new byte[size];
        await ComPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(data,0,size);
        InputData += ComPort.Encoding.GetString(data);
        SetText(InputData);
    }


    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        if (text.Contains("CM"))
        {
            // process the text content here

        }
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Instead of mentioning a link can you give some sample code on how async/await help OP?

Comment: Adding yet another link doesn't improve your comment, in my opinion.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani sure, i'm on it... i was thinking maybe someone got ahead of me first...

Comment: @zhack take your time. Its not about who gives answer first, but who gives the right answer that can really help OP.